Synthesizing decidablity for Finset.filter
I am trying to prove a statement about tiling a board with dominos. As part of the proof, I need to decompose the dominos into horizontal and vertical ones. Using Finset.filter requires a proof that the classification predicate is decidable, which isn't generated automatically. The proof itself isn't long, but it seems very cumbersome to require such a proof whenever Finset.filter is used. Is there a simpler way?
Here is a simplified code snippet illustrating the problem:
inductive Truth
| Yes
| No
deriving Repr

def truth : Truth → Prop
| Truth.Yes => true
| Truth.No => false

#eval Finset.filter truth {Truth.Yes}


Zeroth, a small diversion: You're using true and false as Props.
These values, however, are instances of Bool, which unlike propositions is a data-type. If it has to, Lean coerces them into the propositions true = true and false = true, respectively, but it's more standard and better to use True and False instead.

The signature of Finset.filter is
{α : Type u_0} (p : α → Prop) [DecidablePred p] (s : Finset α): Finset α

Notice that the parameter that carries the proof of decidability of p is in square brackets. This means that Lean will automatically try to synthetize the argument using Type classes.
This essentially means that Lean will look for any instance of a type DecidablePred p. For Lean to find it, we just need to declare one:
instance: DecidablePred truth
| Truth.Yes => Decidable.isTrue truthOfYes
| Truth.No => Decidable.isFalse falsityOfNo


Here's a complete example:
import Mathlib.Data.Finset.Basic
import Mathlib.Data.Finset.Defs
import Mathlib.Data.Finset.Filter

inductive Truth
| Yes
| No
deriving Repr

def truth : Truth → Prop
| Truth.Yes => True
| Truth.No => False

def truthOfYes: truth Truth.Yes := trivial       -- or `rfl` for `true`
def falsityOfNo: ¬ truth Truth.No := False.elim  -- or `Bool.noConfusion` for `false`

instance: DecidablePred truth
| Truth.Yes => Decidable.isTrue truthOfYes
| Truth.No => Decidable.isFalse falsityOfNo

def value := Finset.filter truth {Truth.Yes}


Another possibility: use instDecidableTrue and instDecidableFalse.

In other words, whenever I use Finset.filter, I need to attach a few more lines to show that the predicate is decidable? This makes Finset very cumbersome to use.
